# Donet test doesn't parallelize test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

When I execute this command for parallelized my unit tests it unfortunately only execute sequentially

```
dotnet test "./projectRepo" --settings:projectRepo\test.runsettings
```

my project test is a .net 5 one based on MsTest v2

**The test.runsettings file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- MSTest adapter -->
  <MSTest>
    <Parallelize>
      <Workers>3</Workers>
      <Scope>MethodLevel</Scope>
    </Parallelize>
  </MSTest>
    </RunSettings>
```

Comment: I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#visual-studio-2019-version-164-and-later) using Visual Studio and it seems to work for me.  Perhaps try this?

Comment: I already tried this guide but I encountered this error : "A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'. Failed to run as a self-contained app. - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\publish\testhost.runtimeconfig.json' was not found."